# Xorg stuck at 100% CPU after updates, can't use mouse or keyboard 16.10

Tags: xorg, 16.10, intel

I can no longer use my ubuntu installation at all except via SSH following a reboot after a powercut. The Xorg process is stuck at 100% cpu and I can't use a mouse and keyboard to interact with the system.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/HighCPU

I've read this page and it doesn't appear to be any of the problems listed there, nor does the issue seem to show in my syslog or Xorg log files as far as I can see

How do I best troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Did you recently switch video cards or install anything like Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

If

```
 dpkg -l '*xserver-xorg-video-*' | grep ii
```

doesn't produce video drivers, then you need to reinstall those. I would also try reinstalling xorg after saving your configuration.

Comment: Video drivers are installed, I'm using intel onboard video for output.

I've noticed the problem only occurs when connecting via a HDMI cable.